# Issue when trying to read MNIST data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, mnist

I am about to learn about Neural Networks and I am about to reproduce a tutorial which trains a Neural Network with the target to identify handwritten letters. The training of the Neural Network should be done with the MNIST data set. Unfortunately, exactly where my issue comes as I am not able to read in the MNIST data set.
The environment I am using is a Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.

These are the lines of code I have (line 2 causes the issue):

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)
```

Line 2 causes this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Ok, what the error tells me, is clear. Reason is, that in my tensorflow installation folder a directory **/tensorflow/contrib/...** does not exist.

The issues is caused by line 2, as the module **input_data.py** contains this line of code:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
```

So, the core of my issue is, that I do not know, where to get the module read_data_sets from. I was searching at **GitHub**, but the path
**/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist/**
does not exist there.

In detail: Subfolder **'mnist'** is not to be found in GitHub. Therefore, I also do not find the file **read_data_sets.py**.

So, where do I find the missing module **'read_data_sets'**?

Would be great, if someone could help me as this issue stops my attempt to deal with Neural Networks already at the very beginning.

Thanks a lot and kind regards,
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using a new version of tensorflow >= 1.13.0 so you may follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview) if you want to load MNIST dataset

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response! I just checked the proposed link and it seems to solve my issue.